# Sublime Text 2 - Show long line into several

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a really long line in my HTML code I used to see on several lines in Sublime Text (marked as one in the code). But this morning, when I opened ST, this line became one line (in the code && in ST).
It's like there isn't anymore "wall" to block long lines and make them into several of the same max-height.
Does a shortkey exist or an option in ST to change that ? THanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press `CTRL + shift + P` (or `CMD + shift + P` for OS X), type `word wrap`, select `Word Wrap: Toggle`

Answer (score 3):

Go to View and select Word Wrap. Hope this helps.